# Regular expression to allow dash sign

Tags: asp.net, regex

I currently need to allow a "-" sign in this regular expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`.

Comment: Where? And for what purpose?

Comment: basically I have a textbox for identification number which should accept only numbers,letters and a dash

Comment: if you also allow underscore you could use also: `^[-\w]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
^[a-z\d]+[-a-z\d]+[a-z\d]+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zK9pB0/3)**

[image]

The idea is to use insensitive flag to avoid having `A-Za-z` and use only `a-z`. And also use `\d` that's the shortcut for `0-9`.

So, basically the regex is compound of three parts:

```
^[a-z\d]+   ---> Start with alphanumeric characters
 [-a-z\d]+  ---> can continue with alphanumeric characters or dashes
 [a-z\d]+$  ---> End with alphanumeric characters
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add it as the first character after the opening bracket: `^[-a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Or, to match one or more of letters/numbers with a dash in between: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: Hi Rje thanks...with this expression, I can use "-" as the beginning character that has to be disallowed the dash should only come in between the other characters..

Comment: Edited the answer to allow for that.. if that is not what you need, please explain

Answer (score 0):

Hyphen can be included immediately after the open bracket [ or before the closing bracket
] in the character class. You should not include in the middle of the character class, otherwise it will treat as range characters and some Regex engine might not work also.

In your case both are valid solutions

```
(^[-a-zA-Z0-9]*$) - Starting of the Char class  
(^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$) - End of the Char class
```

**Demo:**
http://regex101.com/r/yP3sH7/2